# Unable to get left/right in TreeNode class

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, treenode

I was working on a problem regarding to binary search tree using java. The name of the built-in class in TreeNode. In the solution, it shows

[image]

However, when I did the implementation myself, I am not able to do "root.left" or "root.right". I was wondering if I missed anything? Thanks!

Comment: What is the class definition of `TreeNode`?

Comment: There isn't a built-in class TreeNode, is there?

Comment: @immibis Yes there is. But it doesn't have a "left" or "right". So I cannot do "root.left" or "root.right" in intellJ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing right/left in that way would imply a TreeNode that is implemented in this way:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    public TreeNode<T> right;
    public TreeNode<T> left;
    public T value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the "T" here stand for?

Comment: T is a generic type. Generally reusable data structures, in this case a tree, use the generic type wildcard in the form "?". This is because we may want to have a tree of String or a tree of Integer so I could define each instance like this:  TreeNode<Integer> nodeInt = new TreeNode<Integer>();   or   TreeNode<String> nodeString = new TreeNode<String>();  Have a read of this for a more detailed explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html